# PHP $_POST encoding

Tags: php, post, encode

i've got an problem.

I try to connect to my MySQL-Database with this password:

> `Test12&@_#+.:-;}][{$%!/()?`,*'"`<>

```
public function __construct() {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if (isset($_POST['dbName'])) {
            $this->dbName = $_POST['dbName'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['dbUser'])) {
            $this->dbUser = $_POST['dbUser'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['dbPass'])) {
            $this->dbPass = $_POST['dbPass'];
        }
    }
}


public function connectToDatabase() {
    try {
        $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=' . $this->dbName . ';host=' . $this->dbHost . ';charset=utf8';
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
        );
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass, $options);
        $this->isConnected = TRUE;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        $this->isConnected = FALSE;
    }
}
```

i always get the message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'web3_10'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I think it's because of my overkill password.

How can i get this to work?

Next i have to import a Dump with this:

```
public function importDatabase($dbTarget) {
    $stmt = 'mysql --host=' . $this->dbHost . ' --user=' . $this->dbUser . ' --password=' . $this->dbPass . ' ' . $this->dbName . ' ' . '<' . ' ' . $dbTarget;
    var_dump($stmt);
    exec($stmt, $output, $return);
    if (!$return) {
        $this->dbImported = TRUE;
    }
}
```

same problem here. no import with this password.

How ca i fix this?

Comment: ... I'm not sure what you are expecting us to be able to do, you're using the wrong password / and or your user doesn't have access to the table / database you are trying to connect to, not a lot we can do about that.

Comment: Have you checked that your password string contains exactly what you expect it to contain? As you are using both single and double quotes and for example a `$` sign, how you assign it is pretty important.

Comment: where have you defined your password *in your code*? have you escaped it correctly? can you login with your password via mysql-console? can you use your code if you set your password to something different?

Comment: could it be that in your password you have a `'` in it (after the `*`) and in your password string you sit your password variable between 2 `'`. i think the `'` inside you password is closing the password string and you need to escape it. like when you try and do `$myString = "hel "lo" world!"`

Comment: By the way, what does `$_POST` encoding have to do with this?

Comment: That password has both single and double quotes - simplify the password by removing them

Comment: it is the right password. in phpmyadmin there is no problem with it.
the password comes from an POST an yes there are ' in it.
Ho can i escape the POST for sings like $, ', <, > .... ?

Comment: My problem is, that users generate passwords with this signs. I need tot test all of them.
$_POST because the user enter his password in a form an check if the connection is correctly.
it works with an simle password

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple of problems here, so make sure:

- You escaped your password string correctly (specifically characters like `'` -> `\'`)
- Its actually the correct password (log in via console and see if it works)
- Your user actually has the correct permissions for the tables.

Further, try to print your password string before connecting, and verify it is indeed correct.

Comment: - How i escape the POST correctly?
- Yes it is the right password
- The User has all rights

Comment: @Tom you escape like this: `"unescaped'#"` -> `"unescaped\'\#"` for instance.

Comment: Ist there a function of php? i get the password over a from (POST)